# Need query to subtract the two rows in databricks sql

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table and the data is in below format.

[I need to derive a 3rd row as mentioned in image. It is a calculated column and first row minus second row. ProgramId, Category, ReportMonth, ReportYear same and third row should hav subcategory 3. Net and it should minus from first row and second row for respective months.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxXTD.png)

I need the query in databricks sql

I have tried self join and some lag functions but it doesn't work. Please let me know if I am not making any sense.

Thanks,
MG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do join on the tables filtered on column `Subcategory` to get your desired results.

Use below code for it.

```
SELECT Programid, Category, Subcategory, ReportMon, ReportYea,
       Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep
FROM original_data
UNION ALL
SELECT o.Programid, o.Category, '3. Net' AS Subcategory, '11/2/2023' AS ReportMon, 'FY2024' AS ReportYea,
       o.Oct - e.Oct, o.Nov - e.Nov, o.Dec - e.Dec, o.Jan - e.Jan, o.Feb - e.Feb,
       o.Mar - e.Mar, o.Apr - e.Apr, o.May - e.May, o.Jun - e.Jun, o.Jul - e.Jul, o.Aug - e.Aug, o.Sep - e.Sep
FROM (SELECT * from original_data where Subcategory='1. Adjusted') o
JOIN (SELECT * from original_data where Subcategory='2. Estimated') e
ON o.Programid = e.Programid
AND o.Category = e.Category
AND o.ReportMon = e.ReportMon
AND o.ReportYea = e.ReportYea
```

Here, i am filtering the records on `Subcategory` and joining them on same
`Programid`,`Category` ,`ReportMon`  and `ReportYea` .

Output:

| Programid | Category | Subcategory | ReportMon | ReportYea | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12234 | ABC | 1. Adjusted | 11/1/2023 | FY2023 | 23455.55 | 45464.43 | 456959.60 | 154531.60 | 54521.45 | 511231.50 | 35235.67 | 47575.23 | 48645.87 | 54524.89 | 11353.14 | 13515.45 |
| 12234 | ABC | 2. Estimated | 11/1/2023 | FY2023 | 15311.23 | 54465.35 | 53531.45 | 5453.45 | 546.40 | 5856.45 | 5454.56 | 452.42 | 458.50 | 5661.46 | 1542.45 | 5145.67 |
| 12234 | ABC | 3. Net | 11/2/2023 | FY2024 | 8144.32 | -9000.92 | 403428.15 | 149078.15 | 53975.05 | 505375.05 | 29781.11 | 47122.81 | 48187.37 | 48863.43 | 9810.69 | 8369.78 |

Comment: Thanks @JayashankarGS. It is working.

Comment: Hi JayashankerGS,
Hi JayashankarGS,
Hi JayashankarGS,

I have another condition for above calculation. I need to another table monthly values and if monthly values exists for each month I need to replace the value from monthly table and calculate the 3. Net Federal. I have tried below but end up with errors.
Monthly column table looks below
mis_year mis_programid mis_name                       mis_oct to mis_sep
2024           abc                1. Adjusted Obligation           23            45
2024           abc                1. Estimated Rebates              23            45
Thanks

Comment: I will check and update.